# Mac - How can I see if Secure input is enabled? Better Touch Tool being blocked by 1password

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, 1password

This happens around 10 times per day for me. I've lived with it for a while, but I can't take it anymore.

Here's what happens:

1. So my computer is in sleep.
2. I 'wake it up' and open Chrome, with a [Better Touch Tool](https://folivora.ai/) (BTT) shortcut: <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>
3. I navigate to Gmail, and I have to log in.
4. To get my login-credentials, I open 1password with the 1password-shortcut: <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> - where I then have to autheticate using my finger-print. After logging into 1password, I get the password, paste it into Gmail and log in. All is good.
5. I then <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to a Word Document, - and then I want to open Chrome again, using *the same* shortcut from step 2. But that doesn't work! In fact, - none of the shortcuts from BTT works.
6. I've discovered that 1password is the culprit. So if I then <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to 1password and close it (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>), then all my shortcuts starts working again.

This seems like a problem 1password has, - but I'm not sure? I can read [here](https://smilesoftware.com/textexpander/secureinput/#1Password), that it (maybe?) has something to do with Secure Input Mode on my Mac, - and that 1password will solve it in version 4. I have version 7. :-/

I assume that it's because 1password gets hidden after I open it the first time, instead of minimize, therefore letting the computer stay in Secure Input mode. But can I fix this somehow? And is that bad (security-wise) to do so?

And can I somehow see if my mac is in Secure Input Mode or not, - so I don't have to 'just try a shortcut and be disappointed' in order to figure it out?

Comment: This post here describes why it occurs: https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/disable-secure-input/2410#post_2 ... But not how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This merely shows *if* it is active: [macOS secure input mode](https://www.nickjvturner.com/blog/2020/08/20/secure-input-mode). To install [TextBar](http://richsomerfield.com/apps/textbar/) and run this script here:

```
#!/bin/bash

SID=`ioreg -l -w 0 | grep SecureInput`
if [[ "$SID" != '' ]]; then
    echo 'Secure Input is Active                  '
else
    echo ''
fi
```

Every 10 seconds. So it gets visible in the menu bar, what enables Secure Input. It works 9 our of 10 times.

It's nice to have an extra indicator, if my shortcuts don't work, because I mis-remember them - or if it's because it's being blocked by Mac.

I'm still missing a script that can unlock Secure Input. Or at least recalculate it, when it's activated for no reason.